# change the over all product url

Tags: magento-1, url-rewrite, product-urls, geturl

I have a big doubt in forming url for products. Currently url is formed by using the name attribute. I want to change this to sku_id(attribute)  of the products. For this where i need to change?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.3

Comment: it may affect on `seo`....

Answer (score 2):

You can use product sku value in product "URL Key" field.

Or

You can use an extension for custom product URL. Its free and easy to use.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/30396/s/custom-product-urls-seo/

Comment: Thanks. I am new to magento and i don't know where  to set sku_id for url changes. please  refer me the file path for this changes.

Comment: No changes in any file. You can change from admin panel:

admin -> catalog -> manage products -> Edit product or Add new product -> (in General tab ) URL key field.

In URL key write "sku" value.

Comment: I have more than 500 products, and product name as URL key for all products.

Comment: You can update all product's URL Key by CSV...

Comment: Please check and follow like this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987445/how-to-customize-product-url

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to have the `Sku` in products url instead of `name` product, you just have to put your **sku** in the **url key** catalog>product manager>add product>`url key`.
- If you want to add it in url, you can follow this:

Use an **Event Observer** `catalog_product_save_before`

config.xml

```
    <global>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <stockalert>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>yourmodel/observer</class>
                        <method>autoupdateurlKey</method>
                    </stockalert>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_before>
        </events>
    </global>
```

Observer:

```
    public function autoupdateurlKey($observer)
    {
        $product=$observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $oldUrlKey=$product->getOrigData('url_key');

        $Sku=$product->getSku();
        $TypeId=$product->getTypeId();

        // put yourlogic 
        $product->getData('url_key',$YourNewUrl);

         return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean `setData` instead of `getData`?